How to set up streaming of responses from an Azure Function API, which is designed to utilize Azure OpenAI
How can I set up streaming of responses from an Azure Function API, which is designed to utilize Azure OpenAI using Python language, to be consumed by an Angular UI application? This Angular UI application communicates with the Azure Function API through a .NET Core API intermediary. What steps are needed to achieve this streaming functionality effectively?
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from openai import AzureOpenAI
import json

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context):
    try:

        data = req.get_json();
        model_name=data['deployment_id']
        api_base1=data['api_base']

        default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
        token = default_credential.get_token("https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default")

        client = AzureOpenAI(
                            api_version="2023-07-01-preview",
                            azure_endpoint=api_base1,
                            api_key=token.token
                            )
        
        completion = client.chat.completions.create(
              model=model_name,
              messages = data['messages'],
              temperature=0.05,
              max_tokens=500,
              top_p= 0.95,
              frequency_penalty= 0,
              presence_penalty= 0,
              stop=None
              )
        response = completion.choices[0].message.content;

        response_data=json.dumps({"message": response})
        return func.HttpResponse(
        response_data,
        mimetype="application/json",
        status_code=200
        )
       
    except Exception as e:
        error_data= json.dumps({"error_message": str(e)})
        return func.HttpResponse(
        error_data,
        mimetype="application/json",
        status_code=500
        )




please share the code you tried in the above question

@Sampath Updated the code. I haven't tried anything for streaming the response, i am calling to above function app api via Asp.net api and displaying the response in streamlit UI application or Angular. So the requirement is to stream this response. currently i am displaying it once i get the complete response from the function app api.

I have used this link to Stream responses from the OpenAI API in real-time using Python and Server-Sent Events (SSE).

Install the necessary modules (requests, json, and sseclient-py). Install these libraries using pip .
Define the API_KEY variable with your OpenAI API key. Then, implement the performRequestWithStreaming() function to send a POST request to OpenAI's completion endpoint, specifying the desired parameters for the AI model and the prompt. Use sseclient to handle the streaming response and print the text.

Code:
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from openai import AzureOpenAI
import json

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        data = req.get_json()
        model_name = data['deployment_id']
        api_base1 = data['api_base']

        default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
        token = default_credential.get_token("https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default")

        client = AzureOpenAI(
            api_version="2023-07-01-preview",
            azure_endpoint=api_base1,
            api_key=token.token
        )

        completion = client.chat.completions.create(
            model=model_name,
            messages=data['messages'],
            temperature=0.05,
            max_tokens=500,
            top_p=0.95,
            frequency_penalty=0,
            presence_penalty=0,
            stop=None
        )

        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Connection": "keep-alive"
        }
        response = func.HttpResponse(status_code=200, headers=headers)

        for choice in completion.choices:
            response_data = json.dumps({"message": choice.message.content})
            response.add_data(f"data: {response_data}\n\n")

        return response

    except Exception as e:
        error_data = json.dumps({"error_message": str(e)})
        return func.HttpResponse(
            error_data,
            mimetype="application/json",
            status_code=500
        )






For more details, refer to so for StreamingResponse not streaming with generator function.

Another way is to use Streaming JSON responses in ASP.NET Core API with IAsyncEnumerable using this link and git.
Updated code:

import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from openai import AzureOpenAI
import json

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        data = req.get_json()
        model_name = data['deployment_id']
        api_base1 = data['api_base']

        default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
        token = default_credential.get_token("https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default")

        client = AzureOpenAI(
            api_version="2023-07-01-preview",
            azure_endpoint=api_base1,
            api_key=token.token
        )

        completion = client.chat.completions.create(
            model=model_name,
            messages=data['messages'],
            temperature=0.05,
            max_tokens=500,
            top_p=0.95,
            frequency_penalty=0,
            presence_penalty=0,
            stop=None
        )

        # Generator function to stream the response data
        def stream_response():
            headers = {
                "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                "Connection": "keep-alive"
            }
            yield func.HttpResponse(headers=headers)
            
            for choice in completion.choices:
                response_data = json.dumps({"message": choice.message.content})
                yield f"data: {response_data}\n\n"

        return func.HttpResponse(stream_response(), status_code=200, mimetype="text/event-stream")

    except Exception as e:
        error_data = json.dumps({"error_message": str(e)})
        return func.HttpResponse(
            error_data,
            mimetype="application/json",
            status_code=500
        )



Thank you for the Solution, with this code i am getting HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'add_data' error.
